# How to integrate Gauge with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, getgauge

I am somewhat familiar with Gauge testing tool and am now working on executing it via Jenkins.

First: i set `gauge --version` in the "Execute Windows Batch Command" field. This was the output:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\jenkins\workspace\Run_Gauge_Test
[Run_Gauge_Test] $ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson8329964667758110371.bat

C:\jenkins\workspace\Run_Gauge_Test>gauge --version 
Gauge version: 0.6.2

Plugins
-------
No plugins found
Plugins can be installed with `gauge --install {plugin-name}`

C:\jenkins\workspace\Run_Gauge_Test>exit 0 
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Compare this to the output I get if I run Gauge directly in command line:

```
C:\jenkins\workspace\Run_Gauge_Test>gauge --version
Gauge version: 0.6.2

Plugins
-------
html-report (2.1.1)
java (0.5.1)
xml-report (0.1.3)
```

So i put the same command in a batch file and ran it only to get the "no plugins found" message again.
As a last option I ticked the `Use custom workspace`and set my directory to a folder where I usually run gauge tests from command line but still it is "no plugins found"

Then i tried running it as a shell command. Output:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\jenkins\workspace\Run_Gauge_Test
[Run_Gauge_Test] $ sh -xe C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson211231385407124893.sh
The system cannot find the file specified
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "C:\jenkins\workspace\Run_Gauge_Test"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    (truncated)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Of course, I am going to actually run the gauge tests(and it doesnt work) rather than just get the version; but I thought it would be simpler to troubleshoot why it doesnt get plugin details correctly.
Any clues?

Comment: Can you check if you did run the command manually on Jenkins and via CI using the SAME user account?

Comment: Hi @apoorvam Just got started with jenkins so im not sure I understand. Do you mean jenkins user account or Windows user accounts? I created a admin acc on Jenkins but for some reason it wouldnt accept the password . So I disabled the security as described here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security. Do you think this is causing the problem? or do i need to specify my windows acc credentials somewhere? I'll try by creating d admin acc again.

Comment: Gauge plugins should be installed via user/admin account with which the Jenkins agent executes commands. Have a look at this doc: http://getgauge.io/documentation/user/current/advanced_readings/ci_integration/go.html for integrating with GoCD and few other CI tools.

Comment: @apoorvam : here's what I did: Reinstalled Jenkins. put the default security back in. Logged in with Admin acc. Ran the command. Worked fine. So I guess the absence of Jenkins admin login caused the problem. Thanks for the advice. If u put your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gauge plugins should be installed via user/admin account with which the Jenkins agent executes commands. Have a look at following doc for more on integrating with GoCD and few other CI tools.
https://docs.gauge.org/latest/howto/index.html#tutorials

Long answer:

**Currently**, Gauge executable is installed at system level. Whereas Gauge plugins(language runners, reporting plugins etc) are installed at a user level. So if you install plugins as one user manually and on CI if task is run against different user, `gauge` will not be able to find plugins.

To fix this, you should run plugin install commands from the account with which CI runs. Or as Srikanth's comment says, you can have `gauge --install-all` task in pipeline. This installs all required plugins on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are installing and using Gauge as different users. As with a lot of CI tools, often the tasks are executed under a different users than one would use to log into the agent.

Currently the way Gauge works is: `gauge.exe` is available at a system level. However, the plugins are installed at a user level.

So if you login as `user1` and do `gauge --install java`, `gauge --version` will list `java` as a plugin only when you are logged in as `user1`.

This is also true if you are running your CI agent under a local system account.

One way you can address this is if you include setup as a task in your pipeline, i.e. have a `gauge --install-all` from your project root before attempting to run your specs.

Comment: Thanks. that helped me understand why I wasnt getting the expected output,